# pytesseractについてです

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tesseract

Jupyternotebook上でコードを書いていたんですが
コード内の機能を使うのにはpytrddrractが必要でTesseractOCRをインストールしました。
仮想環境をmyenvという名前で作成しました。
アクティベートしました。
myenvで
pip install pytesseract
を入力しモジュールをインストールしました。
Jupiternotebookに戻ってコードを実行しても
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'
と表示され動きません。
再起動してみたり、仮想環境の再作成をしてみたり、モジュールをインストールしなおしたりしてみたんですがそれでもやっぱり動きません。。
1時間たちました。。

Comment: 仮想環境はどのような方法で作成されたものでしょうか？（どのツールをお使いでしょうか？）　jupyterのカーネルはその仮想環境になっていますでしょうか？

Comment: Jupyterはどうやってインストールしたのかカーネルの Pythonはどこか, venv？ の Pythonはどこかなど質問に記すとよいかも。「アクティベートしました」ではなく実際に入力したコマンド示すのがよいでしょう。(たぶん別の Pythonで, 別の手法でインストールしたと思われ)

Comment: Jupyterは1年前くらいにインストールしたので覚えてないです。どこというのはパスを書けばよいのでしょうか。Pythonが名前に付くファイルが200くらいあって分からないのですが、Python3.9は"C:\Users\名前\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.9"にありました！pyhon.exeは"C:\Users\名前\myenv\Scripts\python.exe"です！仮想環境はwindowsのコマンドプロンプトで”python -m venv myenv"で作成しました。ツールについてはよく分からないです。Windowsのコマンドプロンプトで”myenv\Scripts\activate”で仮想環境セットしたら名前が変わってコマンドプロンプトにmyenvで実行していますみたいな表示になってそこで"jupyter notebook"と入力して起動しました。先ほど進展があるたました。いつも通りnew押して開いてコードを書いていたんですが、TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.と出ます。

Comment: 関係あるのか分かりませんが前と変わったことといえば、システム環境変数のPathの設定で編集で新規”C:\Users\なまえ\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe”を追加しました。返信の仕方が分からなくてこれで返信できているのか分からないですが、いろいろありがとうございます。